# How to make dynamic navigation with monk and expressjs

Tags: mongodb, express, monk

I have a collection named as "categories". How can i implement it in each page into views jayout.jade like this:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  if categories
    li.dropdown
      a.dropdown-toggle(href="#",data-toggle="dropdown",role="button",aria-haspopup="true",aria-expanded="false")
        | По категориям 
        span.caret
      ul.dropdown-menu
        each category,i in categories
          li
            a(href="/admin/addpost") #{category.name}
```

I try to use monk with mongo. Thanks!